# Personal organizer software for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, contacts

I'm looking for suggestions for software that reminds me of the birthdays and anniversary of friends, like MS Outlook. I also need to be able to import contact details from Outlook to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to give a chance to [**Evolution**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/evolution/) (Available in the ***Software Center***), which is one of the various alternatives to Outlook in Ubuntu.

[**This video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CiSX3rkl98) shows the easy steps for how to process a `.pst` file in order to import your **Address Book** the same as your Mail, Appointments, Tasks and Journal entries in the same process for a created account in Evolution, after which you can work with your data with ease from within Evolution.

[image]

*Please notice that the picture was taken as a screenshot in the video.*

I am aware that other software, such as Thunderbird offers the same workarounds but I prefer Evolution.

Evolution integrates in Ubuntu so that you'll receive notifications of new email (if properly configured), appointment's reminders and/or birthdays/anniversaries from your contacts (as you wish).

If you need further support, don't hesitate to drop a comment.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird (and I assume Evolution) is a multipurpose email client, just like Outlook. It supports contacts and calendars, including birthdays.

Thunderbird should be installed by default if your'e running a recent version of Ubuntu. If not, open the Software Centre and search for it, or from the commandline enter `sudo apt-get install thunderbird`

To import contacts in Thunderbird:

1. Go to 'Tools' > 'Import...' and select 'Address Books'
2. Select the file type that you exported from Outlook (LDIF, .tab, .csv. .txt, or .vcf)
3. Select the file you wish to import. Make sure the filetype/extension is correct.

It should import everything without issue although there may be problems with certain fonts/font-encodings as per https://askubuntu.com/q/281940/16835

Comment: Thunderbird by itself is 'just' a mail client. If you want calendar functionality, you can install the lightning extension.